# import js not found in Glitch

Tags: javascript, aframe

I use Glitch to write a WebVR prject. If I set the script direct in views/index.html, it works well. But if I save the script in js/openclosedrawer.js and import it in index.html. This .js file would not found.
The project ist here:
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/skill-lab
Does somebody know the reason?
Thanks in advance.

```
<script src="../js/openclosedrawer.js"></script>
<script>
  /**
  AFRAME.registerComponent('openclosedrawer',{

    schema: {
      open : {default: '1.8 0 0.1'},
      close : {default: '0 0 0.1'},
      dur : {default: 300},
      closed : {default: "true"}
    },

    init: function (){
      var data= this.data;
      var el=this.el;
      var closed=true;

      var move=document.createElement("a-animation");
      move.setAttribute("begin","click");
      move.setAttribute("attribute", "position");
      move.setAttribute("from", data.close)
      move.setAttribute("to", data.open);
      move.setAttribute("dur", data.dur);
      move.setAttribute("direction", "alternate");

      el.appendChild(move);

    }
  });**/
```

Comment: With same code it works in CodePen. But in Console show also that: Uncaught ReferenceError: ***function is not defined.

Comment: it works on a blank glitch without a server.js https://workable-athlete.glitch.me/

Comment: thanks. @Piotr Adam Milewski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Your server.js, You only expose the 'public' folder

```
// http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

When You change Your component path to public/js/openclosedrawer.js, it works fine. My remix [here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/spice-wilderness?path=public/js/openclosedrawer.js:1:0).

Comment: Check out my remix i literally just added the 'public/' line